# It's possible pass a JFrame as parameter and I get the fields that I created?

Tags: java, swing, parameters, jframe, jtextfield

By example, I want to take the value from an JTextField. In the JFrame I can do this with a simple `txtField.getText()`, but how I do passing the JFrame like parameter?

```
static boolean validateFields(Webcrawler wc) {
    try {
        //I created the txtUrl in the original JFrame, I can take him there, 
        //but not here.
        //The code is from the JFrame is generated by Netbeans.
        wc.getTxtUrl().getText(); //<-- is something like this I want to do.
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the member variables for your input widgets (like JTextFields) are private and hence inaccessible from the outside.
Either declare them public, or write accessor functions for their values. Something on the line of (inside your JFrame or a class derived from that JFrame if it is created by a third party:

```
public String getTxtFieldText () {return txtField.getText ();}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing what you want to do.

1) Expose the text fields you need to validate.  e.g. expose public TextField getUrlTextField() from within your JFrame.  Then within your validate method that accepts the JFrame, you can pull out the text of all of the fields.

DO NOT DO THIS.  You're mixing the validation logic with the View (the JFrame).

Instead, you should use a Controller class that serves as an intermediary between your View (the JFrame) and the Model that is validating it.  In particular, see how NetBeans Platform does its options panels using an [OptionsPanelController](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-options-api/org/netbeans/spi/options/OptionsPanelController.html).  This [blog post](http://blogs.kiyut.com/tonny/2007/09/05/netbeans-platform-options-dialog/) has a good example.

Comment: The validation I want to do is the validation of GUI elements, not processment validation, so I think in this case I'm not mixing the things. I only doing this in another class for organization, but I can do this in the JFrame class too. Another thing, I will use this to set values in the JFrame too, so even this case was incorrect, I need this to other cases too.

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass a reference of once object to another via a method or (here more likely) a constructor parameter.  You could also get a reference to the top-level Window (here your JFrame) via SwingUtitlies' getWindowAncestor method.

But as already commented on in an answer here (+1), you seem to be mixing program logic with user interface and that may not be something you should be doing.